# Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" JsonADDomainExtension

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have terraform script which make a domain join with the code below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "join-domain" {
  name                 = azurerm_virtual_machine.client.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.client.id
 // resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  //virtual_machine_name = azurerm_virtual_machine.client.name
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "JsonADDomainExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.3"

  # NOTE: the `OUPath` field is intentionally blank, to put it in the Computers OU
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Name": "${var.active_directory_domain}",
        "OUPath": "",
        "User": "${var.active_directory_domain}\\${var.active_directory_username}",
        "Restart": "true",
        "Options": "3"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Password": "${var.active_directory_password}"
    }
SETTINGS

  depends_on = ["null_resource.wait-for-domain-to-provision"]
}
```

After the code run, it gets the error below in Terraform:

```
 Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'pocvde-client'. Error message: \"Exception(s) occured while joining Domain 'pocvde.local'\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionwindowstroubleshoot "
   on modules/windows-client/4-join-domain.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "join-domain":
    1: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "join-domain" {
```

I have checked the windows client logs in C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.JsonADDomainExtension, i got the trace below:

```
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1176834Z    [Info]: Get Domain/Workgroup Information
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1645880Z    [Info]: Current domain:  (), current workgroup: WORKGROUP, IsDomainJoin: True, Target Domain/Workgroup: pocvde.local.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1802137Z    [Info]: Domain Join Path.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1802137Z    [Info]: Current Domain name is empty/null. Try to get Local domain name.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1958114Z    [Info]: In AD Domain extension process, the local domain is: ''.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.1958114Z    [Info]: Domain Join will be performed.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.3460994Z    [Error]:    Try join: domain='pocvde.local', ou='', user='pocvde.local\AdminAls', option='NetSetupJoinDomain, NetSetupAcctCreate' (#3:User Specified), errCode='1355'.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.3621879Z    [Error]:    Setting error code to 53 while joining domain
2020-06-23T06:30:54.4085771Z    [Error]:    Try join: domain='pocvde.local', ou='', user='pocvde.local\AdminAls', option='NetSetupJoinDomain' (#1:User Specified without NetSetupAcctCreate), errCode='1355'.
2020-06-23T06:30:54.4085771Z    [Error]:    Setting error code to 53 while joining domain
2020-06-23T06:30:54.4241709Z    [Error]:    Computer failed to join domain 'pocvde.local' from workgroup 'WORKGROUP'.
```

I have changed the client vm OS from DataCenter-16 to Windows 10, i got still same error. Increased the waiting time before domain join operation from 12 minutes to 24 minutes, nothing changed.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that the Domain Controller was not set correctly, after solving that domain join operation is done correctly and that solved my problem